# Automation using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to create a script that will launch an application and configure it completely with provided input values.
ex: Launch outlook-> enter default address-> choose connect ->proceed with next options and finish

How can this be achieved using powershell script?

I am able to launch the applications but not sure how to input values to it.

Comment: It's really a big topic. It depends on what application you want to run. PowerShell is probably not the best option, may I know if using PowerShell is a must for you?

Comment: Powershell is first preference. But I am open for other options. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Ths is a very broad topic, and the answer will depend on the specifics of any given application.

Here is a technet article that dscusses various ways to launch an application, with the benefits and drawbacks of each: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are sevaral approaches depending on the app & installer but the basic key is that you must be able to configure the app manually using nothing but command line tools.

If you can do it manually, e.g., one command at a time then scripting the full install becomes easy.

Most/many installers have switches for "silent install" though Outlook is a complicated setup, start there.

Many installers will show there options when you type: InstallerName /?

Usually the options you need are /silent or /q or /quiet and perhaps.

Office has the concept of creating .MST files (t=transform) to provide additional configuration so search for "creating an officer transform" file.

For some apps, you can monitor the registry with a "registry watcher" app and then write a script to make the same/similar settings for each install.

With Outlook, I would first pursue the MST/transform route and ask this question in places where Office and Outlook are discussed.